# Is there an XML specific object (like XElement) that is binary serializable?

Tags: c#, xml, serializable, binary-serialization

I have a use case where I am serializing objects over the wire via MSMQ (mostly strings). When I read the object off the queue I want to be able to tell if the user meant for the object to be a XML or a string.  I was thinking a good way to do this would just be to check the type.  If it's XmlElement than it becomes XML data otherwise it becomes string or CDATA.  The reason I don't want to just check to see if the data is valid XML is that sometimes data will be provided that is supposed to be serialized as a string but is in fact valid XML.  I want the caller to be able to control the de-serialization into string or XML.

Are there any types that are marked as serializable in the .NET Framework like XElement or XmlElement (both which are not marked serializable)?

Comment: Just wondering - are you *after* one, or are you trying to check that there *isn't* one?

Comment: I'm checking to see if there is a class that represents and XML element, exists in the core framework, and is marked serializable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just add a property to the class of the serialized object that tells you what it is?  I'd propose IsXml.

Comment: I could make a wrapper class... right now the class is just string and I was looking for an alternative that represented an XML element, exists in the framework already, and is serializable.

Comment: and that's what I did. thanks for getting my brain started nobugz :)